# Partitioning the set of subsets of [n] of cardinality k into disjoint sets that cover [n]

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that $k$ divides $n$. Let $S$ consists of all subsets of $[n]$ of cardinality $k$. I would like to prove that there is a partition of $S$ into  disjoint subsets $S_1, S_2, \dots$ with $|S_i| = n/k$ for every $i$ so that the following holds for every $i$:
$$\cup_{S' \in S_i} S' = [n] \ .$$

For example, suppose that $n=4$ and $k=2$. Then, 
$$S = \{\{12\}, \{13\}, \{14\}, \{23\}, \{24\}, \{34\} \}$$
and a suitable partition is:
$S_1 = \{\{12\}, \{34\} \}$, $S_2 = \{\{13\}, \{24\} \}$, $S_3 = \{\{14\}, \{23\} \}$.

This result is surely known. Do you know how to prove it or do you have a reference?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution. This problem can be formulated as an edge coloring problem of a complete hypergraph. This is done in this paper:

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81133783.pdf